# Shuffle and Display the Contents of .txt File

Tags: php, file, fopen

I am trying to read, shuffle, then display the contents of a text file.  The text file contains a list of codes (each one on a new line - no commas etc).

```
1490
1491
1727
364
466
//...
783
784
786
```

My code:

```
$file = fopen("keywords.txt", "r");
shuffle($file);

while (!feof($file)) {
  echo "new featuredProduct('', ". "'". urlencode(trim(fgets($file))) ."')" . "," . "\n<br />";
}

fclose($file);
```

The result I get is the following:

```
new featuredProduct('', '1490'), 
new featuredProduct('', '1491'), 
new featuredProduct('', '1727'), 
new featuredProduct('', '364'), 
new featuredProduct('', '466'), 
//... 
new featuredProduct('', '783'), 
new featuredProduct('', '784'), 
new featuredProduct('', '786'),
```

I believed that I would have to shuffle the contents of the `$file` variable before looping through and displaying, and as you can see, the shuffle function is not working or I have not used it correctly?

I was expecting to see the list arranged a lot more randomly.

Comment: shuffle() is for array not a file handle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just read your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), then just use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to shuffle the array. And then you can loop over it and display it, like this:

```
<?php       

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    shuffle($lines);

    foreach($lines as $line)
        echo "new featuredProduct('', '". urlencode(trim($line)) ."'),\n<br />";

?>
```

And as I wrote above, `shuffle()` is to shuffle an array. But `fopen()` returns a resource.

Comment: yep, `file()` returns an array which can be shuffled, `fopen()` returns a file pointer so shuffling won't work

Comment: Thank you Rizier123.  I see where I went wrong with fopen( ).  I really appreciate your help.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that the shuffle function in php must have an array in parameter, like you can see here :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_shuffle.asp
so you must begin by initiate an array, add all your values to it : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp
 then shuffle, like :

```
    $file = fopen("keywords.txt", "r");
    $a=array();
    while (!feof($file)) {
        array_push($a,urlencode(trim(fgets($file))));
    }
    fclose($file);
    shuffle($a);
    // And here you display your array shuffled.
```

I hope I've helped you a bit.

Comment: Thank you.  This is also useful and works with my while loop example.