# Remove Duplicate Lines in Text File

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have a text file which I am trying to remove duplicate lines.

**Text file example:**

```
new featuredProduct('', '21640'), 
new featuredProduct('', '24664'), 
new featuredProduct('', '22142'), 
new featuredProduct('', '22142'), 
new featuredProduct('', '22142'), 
new featuredProduct('', '22142'), 
new featuredProduct('', '22142'),
```

**The PHP Code I've tried:**

```
$lines = file('textfile.txt');
$lines = array_unique($lines);
file_put_contents('textfile.txt', implode($lines));
```

The PHP file is called duplicates.php and the textfile is in the same directory.  I would like to be left with only:

```
new featuredProduct('', '21640'), 
new featuredProduct('', '24664'), 
new featuredProduct('', '22142'),
```

The file function is trying to read the file into the $lines array then array_unique() to remove the duplicate entries.  Then put the filtered results back in the same file.

Comment: looks fine, what's the problem you're issuing?

Comment: Your code works. maybe replace last line by `file_put_contents('textfile.txt', $lines);`

Comment: perhaps this is what you want? `file_put_contents('textfile.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));`

Comment: How can you use array_unique on a string... try to echo $lines it is a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the new line characters at the end of each line. Because you don't have a new line character at the end of the last line it won't be the same as the others.

So just remove them when you read the file and then add then when you save the file again:

```
$lines = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$lines = array_unique($lines);
file_put_contents('test.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

If yo do: `var_dump($lines);` right after the `file()` call you will see it:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "new featuredProduct('', '21640'), 
"
  [1]=>
  string(36) "new featuredProduct('', '24664'), 
"
  [2]=>
  string(36) "new featuredProduct('', '22142'), 
"
  [3]=>
  string(36) "new featuredProduct('', '22142'), 
"
  [4]=>
  string(36) "new featuredProduct('', '22142'), 
"
  [5]=>
  string(36) "new featuredProduct('', '22142'), 
"
  [6]=>
  string(34) "new featuredProduct('', '22142'), "
       //^^ See here                            ^ And here
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer Rizier123.  Much appreciated sir.  Thank you

Comment: @Hexana You're welcome. Have a nice day :) (You know I could say now, that I use the flags from file() for a reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30350862 :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is about PHP and I don't know either you use Linux / Unix or Windows, but there is one really nice bash solution to get rid of duplicates that will work way faster for big files I think. You can even execute it from PHP with a system call:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$string = file_put_contents('textfile.txt');
$splitstr = explode('),', $string );
$str = implode('),',array_unique($splitstr));
var_dump($str);
```